# How to subtract the elements of two arrays at the same index in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

i am trying to find the average completion time of reported incidents in my mongodb using spring data.

What i want to find is the average completion time of incidents per serviceRequestType. The completion time must me the subtraction of completionDate and creationDate.

I have a collection incidents and a document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5c451b7ab5bd0fd4a6d9b4ba",
    "serviceRequestType": "Type A",
    "status": "Completed",
    "creationDate": "2014-01-18T00:00:00",
    "completionDate": "2014-01-21T00:00:00",
    "streetAddress": "5541 W CATALPA AVE"
}
```

I tried this:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
  group("serviceRequestType").addToSet("creationDate").as("start")
                             .addToSet("completionDate").as("end"),
  unwind("end", "endArray"),
  unwind("start", "startArray")

AggregationResults<Query4Result> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "incidents", Query4Result.class);

return result.getMappedResults();
```

But it produces

```
{_id=TypeA, start=2014-04-07T00:00:00, end=2014-05-12T00:00:00, 
endArray=0, startArray=0}
{_id=TypeA, start=2014-04-06T00:00:00, end=2014-05-12T00:00:00, 
endArray=0, startArray=1}
{_id=TypeA, start=2014-04-05T00:00:00, end=2014-05-12T00:00:00, 
endArray=0, startArray=2}
{_id=TypeA, start=2014-04-07T00:00:00, end=2014-07-09T00:00:00,             
endArray=1, startArray=0}
{_id=TypeA, start=2014-04-06T00:00:00, end=2014-07-09T00:00:00,     
endArray=1, startArray=1}
{_id=TypeA, start=2014-04-05T00:00:00, end=2014-07-09T00:00:00, 
endArray=1, startArray=2}


{_id=TypeB, start=2014-04-07T00:00:00, end=2014-05-23T00:00:00, 
endArray=0, startArray=0}
{_id=TypeB, start=2014-04-06T00:00:00, end=2014-05-23T00:00:00, 
endArray=0, startArray=1}
{_id=TypeB, start=2014-04-05T00:00:00, end=2014-05-23T00:00:00, 
endArray=0, startArray=2}
{_id=TypeB, start=2014-04-07T00:00:00, end=2014-05-20T00:00:00, 
endArray=1, startArray=0}
{_id=TypeB, start=2014-04-06T00:00:00, end=2014-05-20T00:00:00, 
endArray=1, startArray=1}
{_id=TypeB, start=2014-04-05T00:00:00, end=2014-05-20T00:00:00, 
endArray=1, startArray=2}
```

Any other idea on how to to subtract completion and creation date of each document per serviceRequestType

Answer (score 0):

The MongoQuery should look something like this:

```
db.getCollection('incidents').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$serviceRequestType" ,
        "totalMinutes": {
            "$sum": {
                "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ {$dateFromString : {"dateString": "$completionDate"}}, {$dateFromString : {"dateString": "$creationDate"}}] },
                    1000 * 60
                ]
            }
        },
        "count": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }},
    {$project : {"serviceRequestType" : 1, "averageTime": {$divide : ["$totalMinutes", "$count"]}}}

])
```

If your dates are already in ISODate you can skip the datefromstring method.